# how to get the count of the primary key of one table to another table using EFCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I Have to tables Table A and Table B
and it is connected via QuestionID via foreign Key to Table A
see Image[TableA and Table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP4x0.png)

I have this queries base on the tables on the image

```
var tableBquestionIDs = await _dbContext.TableB.Select(q => 
                              q.QuestionID).toListAsync();

var tableAQuestionIDs = await _dbContext.TableA.Where(r => 
                           tableBquestionIDs.Contains(r.QuestionID))
                           .Select(r => r.QuestionID)
                          .ToListAsync();
```

This is an exam program where Table B is all the question to the exam and Table A is the answers of the user.
each question has two choices AnswerID that is why the QuestionId appears twice in one Group in TableA. Once the user answered all the question. which is the TableA.ID 1 to TableA.ID 6. he finishes the exam. now the user is allowed to retake the exam. This TableA.ID 7 to TableA.ID 12
is the retake. what i want to achieve is to get how many times does the user took the exam. that's why in this example the answer is 2.

Can someone help me how can I accomplish this query in EF Core.
I badly need your help as I was stock here for days now
TIA.

Comment: What code do you have so far? What are your expected results?

Comment: all I have is the query where I can get the value from TableA and TableB. the result that i am expecting Count Of value of TableB in TableA as A Group. like in the example on the image the result is 2

Comment: Ok please [edit] and add what you have so far into your question, as *text* not images

Answer (score 0):

Your question has answer: use grouping.

```cs
 var query =
    from b in _dbContext.TableB
    join a in _dbContext.TableA on b.QuestionID equals a.QuestionID
    group b by a.QuestionID into g
    select new 
    {
        QuestionID = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count()
    };
```

Comment: This is the real scenario. this is an exam program where Table B is all the question to the exam and Table A is the answers of the user.
 each question has two choices that is why the QuestionId appears twice in one scenario in TableA. Once the user answer all the question. which is the  TableA.ID 1 to TableA.ID 6. he finishes the exam. now the user is allowed to retake the exam. This  TableA.ID 7 go TableA.ID 12
is the retake. what i want to achieve is how many times does the user took the exam. that's why in this example the answer is 2.

Comment: So, this query should return this information. Just add filter by user.

Comment: thank you. i tried it and this query and this is returning the count of every QuestionID present on TableA. i need the count of all the values in TableB as 1, not individually. appreciate your effort.